# Responsive css menu with multiple levels

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

am having a problem getting multiple levels working on a responsive css menu, the base of the menu i have followed [this tutorial on tuts.com](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-elements/big-menus-small-screens-responsive-multi-level-navigation/)

I need more than 2 sub levels on this menu for my site, though when i add the extra 's to the html, the extra level is not working as it should, am sure its possible to add an extra level to the original menu, but i cant figure out what extra css i need, i had tried adding extra css code for li li li li but thats not working for me.

the extra level displays wwith the 2nd sublevel, where it should only display for the hover of the 2nd sub-menu.

i have created a jsfiddle (my first one) here: http://jsfiddle.net/DizzyHigh/Bpubu/4/

html:

```
<div id="left_container"></div>
<div class="container">
<a class="toggleMenu" href="#">Menu</a>

    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="test">   <a href="#">HOME</a>

        </li>
        <li>    <a href="#">LOCATIONS</a>

            <ul class="nav">
                <li>    <a href="#">Boroughs</a>

                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li>    <a href="#">Enfield</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">E-Locations</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">E-Unit Bases</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">E-Parking</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Barnet</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">B-Locations</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">B-Unit Bases</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">B-Parking</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>    <a href="#">Maps</a>

                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li>    <a href="#">Enfield map</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">ME-Locations</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">ME-Unit Bases</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">ME-Parking</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>    <a href="#">Barnet Map</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">MB-Locations</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">MB-Unit Bases</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">MB-Parking</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>    <a href="#">CONTACT</a>

        </li>
        <li>    <a href="#">LINKS</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="right_container">&nbsp;</div>
```

css:

```
body, nav, ul, li, a  {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
a {text-decoration: none;}
.container {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
.toggleMenu {
    display:  none;
    background: #666;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
}
.nav {
    list-style: none;
     *zoom: 1;
     background:#175e4c;
}
.nav:before,
.nav:after {
    content: " "; 
    display: table; 
}
.nav:after {
    clear: both;
}
.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 9em;
}
.nav a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color:#fff;
}
.nav li {
    position: relative;
}
.nav > li {
    float: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #104336;
}
.nav > li > .parent {
    background-image: url("images/downArrow.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}
.nav > li > a {
    display: block;
}
.nav li  ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
.nav > li.hover > ul {
    left: 0;
}
.nav li li.hover ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.nav li li a {
    display: block;
    background: #1d7a62;
    position: relative;
    z-index:100;
    border-top: 1px solid #175e4c;
}
.nav li li li a {
    background:#249578;
    z-index:200;
    border-top: 1px solid #1d7a62;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .active {
        display: block;
    }
    .nav > li {
        float: none;
    }
    .nav > li > .parent {
        background-position: 95% 50%;
    }
    .nav li li .parent {
        background-image: url("images/downArrow.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 95% 50%;
    }
    .nav ul {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
   .nav > li.hover > ul , .nav li li.hover ul {
        position: static;
    }

}
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var ww = document.body.clientWidth;


        $(".nav li a").each(function() {
            if ($(this).next().length > 0) {
                $(this).addClass("parent");
            };
        })

        $(".toggleMenu").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            $(".nav").toggle();
        });




    adjustMenu();
    var adjustMenu = function() {
        if (ww < 768) {
            $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "inline-block");
            if (!$(".toggleMenu").hasClass("active")) {
                $(".nav").hide();
            } else {
                $(".nav").show();
            }
            $(".nav li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
            $(".nav li a.parent").unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {
                // must be attached to anchor element to prevent bubbling
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent("li").toggleClass("hover");
            });
        } 
        else if (ww >= 768) {
            $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "none");
            $(".nav").show();
            $(".nav li").removeClass("hover");
            $(".nav li a").unbind('click');
            $(".nav li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
                // must be attached to li so that mouseleave is not triggered when hover over submenu
                $(this).toggleClass('hover');
            });
        }
    }
$(window).bind('resize orientationchange', function() {
        ww = document.body.clientWidth;
        adjustMenu();
    });
})
```

can any css gurus point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bryn try the follwing code:

I use 'NormalMenu' class for css hover event on normal menu

**Java Script**

```
var adjustMenu = function() {
 if (ww < 768) {                
    $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "inline-block");
    if (!$(".toggleMenu").hasClass("active")) {
        $(".nav").hide();
    } else {
        $(".nav").show();
    }
    $('.nav').removeClass('NormalMenu').find('ul').hide();              
    $(".nav li a").unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {
            // must be attached to anchor element to prevent bubbling
        e.preventDefault();
        var _sub = $(this).siblings('ul')
        if($(_sub).is(':visible')){
            $(_sub).hide(); 
            $(_sub).find('ul').hide();
        }else{
            $(_sub).show(); 
        }
    });
 } 
 else if (ww >= 768) {        
    $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "none");        
    $(".nav li a").unbind('click');
            $(".nav").show().addClass('NormalMenu').find('ul').removeAttr('style');     
 }
}
```

**CSS**

```
body, nav, ul, li, a  {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
a {text-decoration: none;}
    .container {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
.toggleMenu {
    display:  none;
    background: #666;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
}
.nav {
    list-style: none;
     *zoom: 1;
     background:#175e4c;
}
.nav:before,
.nav:after {
    content: " "; 
    display: table; 
}
.nav:after {
    clear: both;
}
.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 9em;
}
.nav a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color:#fff;
}
.nav li {
    position: relative;
}
.nav > li {
    float: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #104336;
}
.nav > li > .parent {
   /* background-image: url("images/downArrow.png");*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}
 ul.NormalMenu ul{       
    width: 100%;
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
 }
ul.NormalMenu li{        
    line-height:40px;
}


ul.NormalMenu  li:hover > ul{       
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    left:0; 
}
ul.nav ul li{
    background: #1d7a62;        
 }
ul.NormalMenu  li li:hover> ul{       
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    top:0;
    left:100%;        
    }
ul.nav ul li li{
    background: #1d7a00;
 }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.active {
    display: block;
}
.nav > li {
    float: none;
}
.nav > li > .parent {
    background-position: 95% 50%;
}
.nav li li .parent {
    /*background-image: url("images/downArrow.png");*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 95% 50%;
}

 ul.nav ul{
    margin-left:5%;   
     width: 95%;
   } 
ul.nav li{
    line-height:30px;

}
```

}

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ducwidget/Bpubu/21/

Comment: Works great, thanks dumitru, i will have a look at your code in details to see whats diffirent to my version

Comment: I think i am missing something and cant find it for the life of me, your menu has all the submenus hidden when you click the menu button, on the first click mine displays with all submenus open, i have tried various ways of hiding the nav, uls but cant get them to hide, the second click everything is hidden as it should be i have updated the fiddle as i added extra code so the main links are still clcikable with the arrow furthur to the right to clcik and open the sub menus http://jsfiddle.net/DizzyHigh/Bpubu/23/

Comment: **First :** don't use for submenu css class **nav**. **Secondly** I comment code that you don't use. See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ducwidget/Bpubu/25/)

Comment: ahh thanks, i see where i was going wrong now, thankyou once again for your help.

Answer (score -1):

you can check this out ...I have made this menu in Plain html5 and css https://github.com/Saransh27/Dashboard. You can always extend it to you needs and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: You should try to help the OP with his particular problem in the first place. Recommending to dump his code and use another solution is not really an answer to the question, especially not if it's your own product you're promoting.